# using two inner join in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like below pictures :

users table :

[image]

offer_comments

[image]

`offer_comments` table stores comments and answer to comments.
by using below function I can get comments and answer to comments depending on `$id`.

```
function getCommentsAnItem($id){

    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    $result_comments = mysql_query("select e.comment as comment,m.comment as answer_to_comment 
    from offer_comments e 
    inner join offer_comments m on e.id = m.quet 
    where e.offer_id=$id and e.confirm=1");
    $comments = array();
    while($a_comment=mysql_fetch_object($result_comments)){

        $comment = array(
        'comment'=>$a_comment->comment,
        'answer'=>$a_comment->answer_to_comment
        );
        array_push($comments,$comment);
    }

    return $comments ;
}
```

now,I would like to use inner join instead of `offer_comments`, how can I do ?
I would like to use below sql instead of `offer_comments` :

```
select offer.*,u.id,u.name,u.family from offer_comments offer
        inner join users u on offer.id=u.id
```

like :

```
    $result_comments = mysql_query("select e.comment as comment,m.comment as answer_to_comment 
    from (select offer.*,u.name,u.family from offer_comments offer
    inner join users u on offer.id=u.id) e 
    inner join offer_comments m on e.id = m.quet 
    where e.offer_id=$id and e.confirm=1");
```

but it returns `[]` !!

Comment: Do you have more that one column called `id` in your derived table (`e`)? `select offer.*..` is never a good approach try specifying each column instead (or at lest the ones you need)

Comment: ok, I need id
offer_id
user_id
comment
quet
confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $result_comments = mysql_query("select e.comment as comment,m.comment as answer_to_comment 
    from (select offer.*,u.name,u.family from offer_comments offer
    inner join users u on offer.user_id=u.id) e 
    inner join offer_comments m on e.id = m.quet 
    where e.offer_id=$id and e.confirm=1");
```

The change here is in the `e` derived table the relation between `users` and `offer_comments` should be `users.id = offer_comments.user_id` and you've done it `users.id = offer_comments.id`

Comment: If I want to read u.name and u.family in php code, how can I do ? comment'=>$a_comment->????

Comment: I do not use php so I cannot help you with that. I just pointed out the `SQL` issue with the relation :)